# .slidetoggle separate divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have looked up virtually every other question to this and none of the fixes have worked for me.  I am trying to have a profile pic that will toggle the bio below it.  Before I add the (this).next  to my slideToggle event, it slides but it slides all instances of the class .bio.  Adding the (this).next breaks the code.  I have the latest jquery.js saved as jquery-1.8.2.js in my folder.  Could it be a css issue? Any insight would be SOO helpful. Thank you.

```
<script>

             $(document).ready(function() {
             $('.bio').hide();

             $('.toggle').click(function() {
             $(this).next('.bio').slideToggle();
             });
             });
</script>


<div class="profile">
            <div class="profilepic">
            <a class='toggle' href="#"><img src="images/charles.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="charles"/></a>
            </div><!-- end of profilepic class -->
            <div class="officerinfo">
            <h4 class='toggle'>Dude McDudeson</h4>
            <br>
            <a href="mailto:duuuude@gmail.com">duuuude@gmail.com</a> 
            <h5><a href="positions.html">President</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            </div><!-- end of officerinfo class -->
            <div class="bio" style="display:none">
            <p>description</p>
            </div><!-- end of bio class -->
            </div><!-- end of profile class -->
```

css

```
/* Profile */
.profile
{
position: relative;
padding-top:20px;
width: 550px;
height: 150px;
}

/* ProfilePic */
.profilepic
{
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

/* Officer Info */
.officerinfo
{
width:420px;
float: right;
}

/* Bio */
.bio
{
width: 420px;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().next('.bio').slideToggle();
```

The `.next()` method doesn't scan through the following elements until it finds one that matches the supplied selector, it always selects either the immediately following element or nothing depending on whether that element matches the supplied selector.

However, your `h4.toggle` element's parent is followed immediately by the `.bio` element, so `$(this).parent().next('.bio')` should work.

You could also do this:

```
$(this).closest('div.profile').find('.bio').slideToggle();
```

I.e., traverse upwards to the containing `.profile` div element and then within that element find a `.bio` to toggle. This is more robust, because it won't be broken if the structure is changed later with other elements inserted before the `.bio` element.

Comment: Ok that second one worked! Thank you so much.  Now that I have that figured out, when the bio expands, it should push down the other profile classes(for example the vice president).  But when I expand the bio, it only pushes down the class officerinfo and bio.  So the higher bio pushes into the profile pic.  I have included the css relevant.  Thanks again for the answer though that was awesome.

Comment: OP has an `<a class='toggle'>` and an `<h4 class='toggle'>`, make sure which one he wants.

Comment: Well the h4 is the name of the officer, and I wanted both the name of the officer AND the profile pic to toggle the bio.   Should I go about this differently?

Comment: I didn't notice (until Sheikh mentioned it) that you had more than one `toggle` element. If you want both to toggle the bio then the second method I showed will work fine, but the `.next()` method won't for the reasons I gave. (You may find that you need to add `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` to your click handler to stop the default anchor element behaviour.) Regarding your CSS issue with elements overlapping or whatever, I'd expect that is unrelated (and should probably be another question), but can you setup a demo at http://jsfiddle.net so that we can see it in action?